# E-Mail | Mit freundlichen Grüßen Alexander und Anja oder Anja und Alexander?

Tags: phrase, valediction

Wie der Title schon sagt, würde ich gern wissen, in welcher Reihenfolge ich die Namen schreiben soll.

> Mit freundlichen Grüßen 
>   Alexander und Anja

oder

> Mit freundlichen Grüßen 
>   Anja und Alexander

Die E-Mail wird von dem E-Mail-Account des Alexanders versendet. Spielt das eine Rolle? Muss der Frauenname trotzdem zuerst geschrieben werden?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about German language but rather about style and manners - Any answer we could give would apply to e-mails written in any language.

Comment: @tofro it is not correct. In my native language it is strong defined. English ist not centre of the universe

Comment: @dir, what is your native language and what is the rule there?

Comment: Wer hat die Email denn geschrieben? Diesen Namen würde ich zuerst erwarten. Bei z.B. Einladungen, die gemeinsam verfasst werden und wo beide zusammen einladen, würde ich die Frau zuerst schreiben.

Comment: @tofro That's not true. This question is legit +1. (At least we in Spanish send the first person *compulsory* at the end, as courtesy, while some other languages wouldn't care or even would proceed the other way around.)

Comment: In my opinion the Q is on-topic in so far as the syntax and style used for (e-)letters is connected with the cultural language space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Es gibt das deutsche Sprichwort "Der Esel nennt sich immer zuerst", dementsprechend ist es höflicher, wenn zuerst die fremde Person (Anja) und dann sich selbst (Alexander) genannt werden.

Comment: Dem würde ich bei Briefen und Emails widersprechen. Hier würde ich immer davon ausgehen, dass diejenige Person,  die den Brief schreibt auch zuerst unterschreibt.

Comment: @Iris: Bei Briefen würde ich eigentlich davon ausgehen, dass *alle* Unterschreibenden mitgeschrieben/mitformuliert haben, sofern nicht "Grüße von ..." vor einem der Namen steht.

Comment: Vorsicht, hier wurde eine falsche Antwort als Lösung markiert. Iris hat recht, denn der Briefschreiber unterschreibt und nennt seine Mitgefährten nachfolgend. Schreiben zwei zusammen den Brief, dann die Hauptperson zuerst, aber wenn es unter denen keine Hauptperson gibt, dann kann es galanter erscheinen, dass die Frau aus Höflichkeit zuerst genannt wird, was jedoch heutzutage in der modernen gleichberechtigten Welt relativ egal ist.

Answer (score 12):

Wenn es sich um eine geschäftliche Korrespodenz handelt, sollte der Ranghöhere immer zuerst genannt werden, dies entspricht dann der [DIN 5008](http://www.wirtschaftsdeutsch.de/lehrmaterialien/korrespondenz-anrede-unterschrift.pdf):

> Bei zwei Unterzeichnenden wird der/die Ranghöhere zuerst angegeben.

Bei informellen Kommunikationen kann man aber auf die DIN Konformität verzichten und es freier formulieren.

Comment: Oh! genau aus diesem Grund ist es keine off-topic Frage. Danke für den DIN Hinweis! In meinem Fall sind beide Teilnehmer gleichberechtigt. Trotzdem gut zu wissen!

Comment: Die Vornamen deuten nicht auf eine geschäftliche Korrespondenz hin, auf die man eine DIN-Norm anwenden würde.